# Problems in passing arguments in gcc

Tags: c#, .net

My Process is GCC.exe which is in the same folder as my executable.
My target is to pass a file as an argument in `gcc` and produce the compiled file.
Why is this not working?

```
  private void btnc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process GCC = new Process();
            GCC.StartInfo.FileName = "gcc.exe" ;
            GCC.StartInfo.Arguments = this.sourcefile.Text;
            GCC.Start();
            GCC.Close();

        }
```

Comment: Can you verify that gcc.exe is actually launching? It could be a path issue.

Comment: Its launching but keeps saying: "no such file or directory"

Comment: because gcc expects a file name as an argument, not a source document?

Comment: That is a file name friend. The problem is this: This is the path in this.sourcefile.Text: C:\Users\abc\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Compiler\Compiler\bin\Debug\my.c But the path is getting truncated to "C:\Users\abc\Documents\Visual " at runtime....what to do????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GCC.Start();` starts a process asynchronously while  `GCC.Close();` kills it. So, skip `Close()`.

Comment: @user667389 how about is `this.sourcefile.Text` ? There is a size  limitation to arguments. It cannot be more than 2047 characters.

Comment: @invalidsyntax yes. if the child process it done, it will disappear.

Comment: A good point. Maybe you should pass in the filename instead of the contents.

Comment: Try Arguments = "\"" + this.sourcefile.Text + "\"";

Comment: ah, the spaces in your path threw it off. Crazy windows.

Answer (score 3):

You are not waiting for the process to end before closing it.
Try: `GCC.WaitForExit()`

Comment: That's pretty vague. What exactly is happening?

Comment: That is a file name friend.
The problem is this:
This is the path in this.sourcefile.Text:
C:\Users\abc\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Compiler\Compiler\bin\Debug\my.c
But the path is getting truncated to "C:\Users\abc\Documents\Visual " at runtime....what to do????